# Trying to use an excel formula from a generated CSV file

Tags: excel, csv

I am trying to get the below excel formula to stay in a single cell when opening a CSV in excel.

```
=IFERROR(IF(match(indirect(\"j\"&row()),K:K,0),Y,),N)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: To stay in a single cell? Which cell? Don't CSVs always open in A1? (I am not entirely certain on that last point but I think that is what I have noticed.

Comment: Can you post at least one sample line of your csv?

Comment: Your Y and N should be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=IFERROR(if(match(indirect(CHAR(74)&row()),K:K,0),CHAR(89),TEXT(,)),CHAR(78))
'alternate
=if(ISNUMBER(match(indirect(CHAR(74)&row()), K:K, 0)), CHAR(89), CHAR(78))
```

This uses alternate methods of producing strings without quotes.